# A trace formula of two noncommutative operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, many-body, partition-function, time-evolution

In many cases of quantum many-body problems, the Hamiltonian $H$ can always be divided into two parts, i.e. $H_0$ and $H'$. In this occasion, one can systemically calculate the partition function throught the formula
$$
Z ~= Tre^{-\beta(H_0+H')} ~=~ Tre^{-\beta H_0}Te^{-\int_0^{\beta}H'(\tau)d\tau}
$$
where

$$H'(\tau)=e^{\tau H_0}H'e^{-\tau H_0},$$

and $T$ is the time ordering operator. Here, I want to ask that how can I prove the above formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. OP's identity follows from standard manipulations in the [interaction picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture), cf. e.g. Ref. 1.
2. Start with the evolution operator
   $$\tag{1} U(t_f,t_i)~:=~\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}H (t_f-t_i) \right), \qquad H~=~H_0+V, $$
   which satisfies the Schrödinger equation
   $$\tag{2} i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t_f}U(t_f,t_i)~=~HU(t_f,t_i).$$
3. Define the evolution operator in the interaction picture
   $$\tag{3} U_I(t_f,t_i)~:=~\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}H_0 (t_f-t_i) \right)U(t_f,t_i) ,$$ 
   and define the interaction Hamiltonian 
   $$\tag{4}  H_I(t_f) ~:=~\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}H_0 (t_f-t_i) \right)V\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}H_0 (t_f-t_i) \right).  $$
4. Show that the evolution operator (3) satisfies the 1st order ODE
   $$\tag{5} -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t_f}U_I(t_f,t_i)~=~H_I(t_f)U_I(t_f,t_i).$$
5. Deduce from (5) that evolution operator $U_I(t_f,t_i)$ in the interaction picture can be written as a time-ordered exponential 
   $$\tag{6} U_I(t_f,t_i)~=~T\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt~H_I(t)  \right).$$
6. Finally, deduce that
   $$\tag{7} {\rm Tr}\left[U(t_f,t_i)\right]
   ~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~{\rm Tr}\left[\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}H_0 (t_f-t_i)\right) U_I(t_f,t_i) \right], $$
   and [wick-rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) in order to obtain OP's identity.

References:

1. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT;* Section 4.2.

Comment: Why doesn't $U_{I}$ need $\exp(-i/\hbar H_{0}\Delta t)$ on the right side?